# Is it possible to inject php code via input fields?

Tags: php, code-injection

I haven't found this question on here yet, and I have done some quick Google research on this but I couldn't really find a clear or good answer to this question.

Is it possible to inject a piece of php code in an input field. that would actually work.

```
//for instance.
//Ill fill in '"test()"' in the field.
<input type="text" name="input" value="'"test()"'">

$injection = $_POST/*(or $_GET)*/['input']; // coming from the input

public function test(){
    echo "injection successful";
}
```

So is this possible?

Comment: Only if you evaluate user input as code instead of treating it as text.  (Same goes for SQL injections.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, but not like that. If you do what you do in your script, then the code would just be assigned as-is (as a string) to the variable $injection.

You can however execute it like this:

```
$injection = $_POST/*(or $_GET)*/['input']; 
eval($injection);
```

There are other ways as well, but all have the same issue: you must actually evaluate the string as code to execute it. `eval` is the most obvious solution for that.

But be very careful when you implement this! If you open such a form for the outside world, everybody can execute any script, including ones that might destroy your server or steal your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you posted is harmless, but depending on what you do with user-supplied data, it *can* be used in an [code-injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). The linked wiki has some examples, here's a couple of them:

```
$posted = $_POST['user_input'];
eval($posted);//<--- NEVER DO THIS
```

However, after 10 years, I've never ***ever*** even gotten close to the point where I had to even worry about dreaming of having to maybe go down this route.
Another, slightly less unlikely possible vulnerability is impropper escaping when passing user-data to `exec`:

```
$cmdArgument = $_POST['flag'];
exec('ls '.$cmdArgument, $return, $status);
```

Could leave you vulnerable if I passed this as a *"flag"* value:

```
-lta && /usr/bin/env php -r 'echo __DIR__;'
```

And use that input to start messing around with your file-system.
To protect agains this, use the `escapeshellarg` and `escapeshellcmd` functions to sanitize the input.

More common, equally dangerous, but easier to overlook, would be this:

```
$requested = $_GET['page'];
require $requested.'.php';
```

Instead, if you want to `require` scripts like this, a safer, and just as easy approach is this:

```
switch ($_GET['page'])
{
    case 'admin':
        require 'admin.php';
        break;
    case 'user':
        require 'user.php';
        break;
    default:
        require 'error.php';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP exec command](https://www.php.net/function.exec) can execute code posted to the server. Otherwise PHP code written in a text box will not be interpereted as PHP but just as a normal string.

Comment: The exec command executes (shell) commands. This can be a script or anything else, but it always refers to something on the server, not to something in the $_POST or $_GET inputs.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Look at my answer, it can be dangerous, if you pass it a `$_POST` or `$_GET` value contianing `&&`

Comment: I know it can be dangerous, but the question was if was possible (and how). If someone asks you if they can buy a gun, you can tell them 'yes' or 'no', but not just give them a flower instead.